# How to customize UITabBar text labels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uitabbar

I have customized a Tab Bar using the methods from Ray Wenderlich and iOS Blog but because I'm using a light color as background the text labels look awful and I want to change them to match my style. Is it possible and how?

If its not possible or if its too complex I would like to ask how to move the icon image down so its centered on the Tab Bar? This way I could "write" the labels on the .png files.

I'm planning on developing this app for iOS5+ so there is no worry about making it compatible with iOS4 (although if anyone finds a easy way of doing this I would really appreciate).

Here's [what I got](http://cl.ly/3h1a3v2G1Y0E0U2i220m) so far and here's [what I want](http://cl.ly/3I1y3J3K3j3L3C0o1L30).

The code for my tabBarBackground:

```
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selection-tab.png"]];
```

And for the Icons:

```
//Custom TabBar Items
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-icon-selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-icon.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = rootTabBarController.tabBar;
//Icons for the 1st Tab
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by accessing the tab-bar item object of the tabbar for each view controller. 
Check out some documentation here for more examples.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html

Answer (score -1):

Use this to customize UITabBarItem text:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: aNSDictionaryOfTextAttributes];
```

with a dictionary of attributes similar to those shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906453/1709073).